# Windows 7 Action Center messages via script

Tags: windows-7, script, wmi

I would like to know how to read, via vbscript, WMI, Powershell etc -the new Windows 7 Action center messages that the user normally gets informed of.

I want to read all those messages on each machine and store then in a central database, then disable the messages from displaying to the user on the local machines.

EDIT: - Once i can read the messages i know how to deal with storing them, my question is how do i programatically read those messages from each Win7 PC

Answer (score 1):

Does Windows 7 log the messages in the Event Viewer?  I don't know if Microsoft has provided any sort of interface to the Action Center directly, so if there are equivalent Event Viewer events, I believe there are ways to query information out of there instead.

**EDIT:** [Here's a WMI script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/479d4a4e-b06b-4464-94b2-5a61af14d82b) to pull data from a computer's event log that might get you started.

Comment: thanks for the script, i already have similar code to read the event logs and i have not seen any of the action center stuff stored in the event logs

Answer (score 1):

You may have been misled by the MS marketing hype calling it `Action Center`. The original name which is found in the documentation is actually `Security Center`.

From [Security Center API](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/bd97d9e6-75c1-4f58-9573-9009df5de19b/):

> I've managed to find these links:
>
> [Windows Security Center](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963845(VS.85).aspx)
>
> "You have some Non Disclosure
>   Agreement document to sign before you
>   get the access to the security center.
>   The interface is not likely availble
>   publicly. The contact information can
>   be found at [Implementing the Teredo
>   Security Model](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190942(VS.85).aspx)"
>
> And there is WMI interface:
>
> **Code Snippet:**
>
> Set oWMI =
>   GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\.\root\SecurityCenter")
>   Set colItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select
>   * from AntiVirusProduct")
>  For Each objAntiVirusProduct In
>   colItems
>  msg = msg &
>   "companyName: " &
>   objAntiVirusProduct.companyName &
>   vbCrLf
>  msg = msg & "displayName:
>   " & objAntiVirusProduct.displayName &
>   vbCrLf
>  msg = msg & "instanceGuid:
>   " & objAntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid &
>   vbCrLf
>  msg = msg &
>   "onAccessScanningEnabled: " &
>   objAntiVirusProduct.onAccessScanningEnabled
>   & vbCrLf
>  msg = msg &
>   "productUptoDate: " &
>   objAntiVirusProduct.productUptoDate &
>   vbCrLf
>  msg = msg &
>   "versionNumber: " &
>   objAntiVirusProduct.versionNumber &
>   vbCrLf
>  msg = msg & vbCrLf
>   Next
>  WScript.Echo msg